# Line through UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have this weird bug with UITextField, sometimes there's a line (actually more of a transparent strip) through it. Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

Here's the picture

[image]

A link to xib file: http://db.tt/7l2Bq42

A link to the code: http://db.tt/DW0mlqQ

**Edit: The bug is now solved. I'm creating this view programmatically rather than with a xib file, and the bug seems to be gone. Thanks everyone for your help**.

Comment: Can you post some code that you used to make it? Does it have accessory views or some such attached?

Comment: are you sure that line is not from another object? (ie, a misplaced UIImageView object, etc)

Comment: Definetly sure that it is not from another object.

Comment: Alos, I noticed that the placeholder text seems to be above the transparent line.

Comment: Is the screenshot from the actual app or a case of Photoshop editing? The line seems to be **above** the text.

Comment: There seems to be an additional line running along the bottom of the text field as well.

Comment: No, this is a screenshot from the app. No Photoshop

Comment: If you zip up the Interface Builder file (.xib) and post it here, it may be helpful to understanding what's going on. Also, any code you can post is helpful.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the xib (see the original post). There is nothing special in code, but I am hiding/unhiding the text fields. Could that be the problem?

Comment: After a short revision of the code, I see that it is not so secret, so I'll post it (original post)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have used center property of UITextField. If you use nameInput1.center, sometimes it gives this type of error.

You can use this line instead of setting center property.

nameInput1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

If you still finding some problem then please let me know. I love to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but the bug is stil present. I've made some changes to the code and I am now setting the frame instead of the center. You had this bug too?

Comment: Hello, Why are you using center property of UITextField? Is there any need for that? Can you please provide me the complete example so that I can debug and solve the problem.

Comment: I'm using it, because I have to set its position. I can't give you the code for the whole app, but I can give you the .h file as well (and than you can make an app out of it). There are some unknown classes, just delete them. And this problem appears only on devices running OS 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the centering, does your problem go away?

You can avoid using textAlignment altogether by subclassing the UITextField and overriding the drawTextInRect: method.  To compute the rectangle, use this NSString method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

Comment: I'm not using textAlignment. Only "half" of the problem went away now that I'm not setting the center property - the line now doesn't appear when both textfields are on the screen. Take a look at the code, maybe you can solve it.